# why nested loop not working in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5.3

here is my view and i don't know why my nested looop not working please help me

```
         <ul>
     @foreach($users as $m)
                <li> {{$m->namecategory}}

                   <ul> 
                   @foreach($m->namesubcategory as $nam)
                          <li>{{$nam->namesubcategory}}

                             <ul>
                               @foreach($nam->namesubling as $lan)
                                    <li>{{$lan->namesubling}}</li>

                              @endforeach
                             </ul>


                          </li>
                      @endforeach
                   </ul>

               </li>

     @endforeach  
         </ul>
```

its throwing error like this

Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View

here is output using dd($users)

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => {#209 ▼
  +"idcategory": 1
  +"namecategory": "mobile and assces"
   +"created_at": null
  +"updated_at": null
  +"idsubcategory": 1
  +"namesubcategory": "mobile"
  +"idcategory_mastercategory": 1
  +"idsubling": 1
  +"namesubling": "iphone"
  +"idsubcategory_subcategory": 1
   }
  1 => {#211 ▼
  +"idcategory": 1
  +"namecategory": "mobile and assces"
  +"created_at": null
  +"updated_at": null
  +"idsubcategory": 2
  +"namesubcategory": "mobile cover"
  +"idcategory_mastercategory": 1
  +"idsubling": 2
  +"namesubling": "nexu cover"
  +"idsubcategory_subcategory": 2
   }
   2 => {#212 ▼
   +"idcategory": 2
  +"namecategory": "elect"
   +"created_at": null
  +"updated_at": null
  +"idsubcategory": 3
  +"namesubcategory": "lap"
  +"idcategory_mastercategory": 2
  +"idsubling": 3
  +"namesubling": "hp"
  +"idsubcategory_subcategory": 3
  }
 ]
```

And i m trying to Achieve this

```
      -mobile and accessory (mastercategory)
        1.mobile(subcategory)
                1.iphone(subling)
        2.mobile cover(subcategory)
               1.iphone cover(subling)

 -electronic(mastercategory)
           1.laptop(subcategory)
                1.hp(subling)
```

Comment: Because `sub` doesn't exist in `$m`?

Comment: Can you print $users array to check if there is an issue in the array

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) There isn't nearly enough detail above to be able to usefully help you.

Comment: @manian i cheched no issue it is have value

Comment: var_dump $users and provide the output on your question please.

Comment: @ChrisTownsend i updated my  question new please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make another array from your collection.
And then you will able to get anything that you need.

```
$result = [];
foreach ($users as $u) {
  $result[ $u-> namecategory ] = $result[ $u-> namecategory ] ?? [];
  $result[ $u-> namecategory ][$namesubcategory] = $result[ $u-> namecategory ][$namesubcategory] ?? [];
  $result[ $u-> namecategory ][$namesubcategory][] = $u-> namesubling;
}
```

In result you will have an array like

```
result [mobile and assces]
            [mobile]
              [iphone]
            [mobile cover]
              [nexu cover]
```

Then you will be able to "foreach" this array like you want to.

Note please, that syntaxis "**$a = $b['xx'] ?? [];**" - PHP7

Answer (score 0):

According to your var_dump, **$m->namesubcategory** - is not an array.
**$m->namesubcategory**, **$nam->namesubling** are not  as well. 
You CANNOT use "foreach" to them.

Comment: any other solution how i can use nested for each or any other method

Comment: i had written html code and what i try to achieve in above is there are any other method or trick that i can follow to achieve that

Comment: I meant to write HTML like this
<ul>
     @foreach($users as $m)
....
     @endforeach  
         </ul>
But without any blade directives. HTML what you want to achieve

Comment: category and subcategory in jstree as written above in last section